# Vega, is it pssible to have duplicate labels in the x axis

Tags: vega

I am trying to replace some charts generated with Google Charts API using Vega.

It is a simple bar chart with 5 columns, and I previously had the x axis labels showing the actual numbers.

[image]

When I try doing this with Vega, it would merge the duplicate numbers into one column.

[image]

Here is the json used for the vega version (its more or less a cut and paste of the quickstart examples with the data values changed).

```
{
    "scales": [
        {
            "range": "width", 
            "type": "ordinal", 
            "name": "x", 
            "domain": {
                "field": "data.x", 
                "data": "table"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "range": "height", 
            "name": "y", 
            "domain": {
                "field": "data.y", 
                "data": "table"
            }, 
            "nice": true
        }
    ], 
    "axes": [
        {
            "scale": "x", 
            "type": "x"
        }, 
        {
            "scale": "y", 
            "type": "y", 
            "ticks": 3
        }
    ], 
    "height": 80, 
    "padding": {
        "top": 10, 
        "bottom": 20, 
        "right": 10, 
        "left": 30
    }, 
    "width": 200, 
    "marks": [
        {
            "from": {
                "data": "table"
            }, 
            "type": "rect", 
            "properties": {
                "hover": {
                    "fill": {
                        "value": "red"
                    }
                }, 
                "update": {
                    "fill": {
                        "value": "steelblue"
                    }
                }, 
                "enter": {
                    "y": {
                        "field": "data.y", 
                        "scale": "y"
                    }, 
                    "x": {
                        "field": "data.x", 
                        "scale": "x"
                    }, 
                    "y2": {
                        "scale": "y", 
                        "value": 0
                    }, 
                    "width": {
                        "band": true, 
                        "scale": "x", 
                        "offset": -1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ], 
    "data": [
        {
            "values": [ 
                { "y": 7,"x": 7 }, 
                { "y": 7,"x": 7 }, 
                { "y": 7,"x": 7 }, 
                { "y": 6,"x": 6 }, 
                { "y": 0,"x": 0 }, 
                { "y": 0,"x": 0 }
            ], 
            "name": "table"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ensure that each object in the `values` array has a unique value for the x-axis. This makes sense: otherwise, how would a user know what each bar referred to? If you wish to label each bar with its corresponding value, then you should use a text mark. See the [grouped bar](http://vega.github.io/vega-editor/?mode=vega&spec=grouped_bar) example for guidance.